# How to pass user and password to Spring REST service with Spring RESTTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

How to pass user and password to Spring REST service with Spring RESTTemplate..

I have a Spring MVC project using Spring Secuirty and I need to write a client with Spring RESTTemplate to access it.. I have the following code but it does not work:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LOGGER.debug("Starting REST Client!!!!");


        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials =
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test","test");

        client.getState().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("127.0.0.1", 8080, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
                credentials);

        CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory commons = new CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(commons);


        String jsonreturn = restTemplate.getForObject("http://127.0.0.1:8080/springmvc-rest-secured-test/json/Regan", String.class);

        LOGGER.debug(jsonreturn);
    }
```

I am getting the spring login screen in my return and not the data I am looking for so this tells me that my credentials is not working..

Comment: Please post your Spring Security configuration file. Have you configured basic authentication? If not, `UsernamePasswordCredentials` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

it would help if you posted the method signature from the server side.  how are you doing your authentication?  here's a get example.  post would be the same but using postForObject()

```
String result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://127.0.0.1:8080/springmvc-rest-secured-test/json/{user}/{password}", String.class, "user", "pass");
```

Comment: I am using basic Spring Security. I believe form based

Comment: Spring security out of the box uses a POST and really isn't a REST service.  The code above wasn't suppose to be correct, it was just a sample of the correct syntax.